# Movie about trying to move the moon to save/cancel summer vacation

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

There's an animated movie (maybe Disney?) where there's a plot to move the moon with a beam, either to cancel or save summer vacation.
I wacthed it as a kid (early 2000's). I think it was in theaters then.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The movie you're looking for is [Recess: School's Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recess:_School%27s_Out), the season 5 finale to the animated television show [Recess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recess_(TV_series)). Alongside the matching plot details, it was made by Disney, had a theatrical run, and premiered in early 2001.

> TJ and company must save summer vacation from disappearing forever.

The plot involves a beam modifying the moon's orbit to change the Earth's climate to get rid of summer.

Here's a relevant clip (spoilers):

Comment: Of course changing the lunar orbit will cause mass die offs of lifeforms that depend on the tides, but won't change seasons much and the changes may take millions of years to become noticeable.  But reducing or eliminating the Earth's axial tilt would reduce or eliminate seasons - and probably cause so much havoc that school attendance would no longer be important.  Dead kids can't go to school.